# I got multiple armature animations. How do I apply these animations to my T-posed character?

Tags: animation, armature

The animations are in different files so:
jogging.dae
idle.dae

neither are skinned.

Than I have my main armature which is skinned and in a t-pose.

How would I use those animations that I have with the other two armatures with the one I have on my main character in T-pose. Note they are all using the same names on the bones, and the same overall amount of bones.

I tried reading up on pose libraries but didn't really uncover anything and the first commented response would have to assume (as far as I know) that both armatures start off the same way, but the run is strictly a run and the T-pose is strictly a T-pose. Transitioning between the two like in a state machine system is what I want really.

Comment: First import the animations to Blender. If you want to store them separately, save as .blend and in your character file go to File->Link or Append and find the animations, append makes editable copies in this file. You can then select your armature and from dopesheet-window -> action editor you can change the active animation.

Comment: That would work I imagine if both armatures started off in the same pose but they don't. The jogging animation literally is a full jog start to finish while the T-pose is just a T-pose. The jog animation seems to have had its animation baked to frames because it has a LOT of keyframes nothing really seems to be tweened.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the start pose is for an animation. The armature for the jogging animation also has had a rest pose / bind pose from where all transformation during the animation is calculated. Even if the frames are baked. The rest pose most often is T-pose or A pose and you could expect to get an animation somewhat ressembling the original. But often you cant match exact bone proportions and it needs more or less fixing by hand.

Comment: Well I've tried and still can't figure this out here is my blend. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41608 If you can explain to me why this is not working I would be happy.

Comment: It took me awhile to figure this out but I was referring to re-targeting using MoCap data.

Comment: I took a look at the .blend and it looks like the bone rolls don't match the animation, During the running the thighs and knees are moving somewhat as expected but bending in wrong direction. Also mocap data necessarily is not configured in T-pose and bone rolls can be set up differently. You could go and try to rotate each bone around the bones Y axis in edit mode until the animations start to look right but
to be able to sensibly use mo-cap you should have access to the original mo-cap armature that was used to set up the animations.